# Почему наезжает текст в Safari?

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, safari

Проблема заключается в том, что в Сафари текст как будто залазит под границу, хотя места там предостаточно для текста. Пробовал увеличить ширину - не помогло. Не знаю, в чем может быть проблема 
Скриншот проблемы - [joxi.ru/J2bljbwI4P3XLr](http://joxi.ru/J2bljbwI4P3XLr)
Сайт - [o3.ua](http://o3.ua) (нужно выбрать укр версию)

Буду благодарен советам

Comment: Safari на Windows или OS? Если на Windows, то скорее всего на нём не стои проверять качество вёрстки сайта, кажется они прекратили поддержку Safari для Windows.

Comment: @CodeSteaker Нет, и на макОсь, и на осях мобильных

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На бок наезжает его псевдо элемент.

```
.slider-wrap .tabs::after {
    left: 831px;  /*недостаточный отступ*/
    background: #5a93dd; /* закрывает собой текст */
    height: 42px;
}

.slider-wrap .tabs::after, .slider-wrap .tabs::before {
    content: '';
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 1px;
}
```

Т.к. after находится "за" `.tabs` он (при наложении) отрисовывается поверх своего элемента.

В фф тоже проявляется хотя и не так сильно.

Comment: Громадное вам спасибо! :)